# What is wrong with this stored function?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Create Or Replace Function  ASS1_TEST_MSG (pName varchar2) Return varchar2 As
vMsg := '';
Begin
    If pName = 'Peter' Then
        vMsg := 'Hello Peter. I am a student in Database Systems.';
    End If;
    Return vMsg;
End;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the datatype of `vMsg`,

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION ASS1_TEST_MSG(
          pName VARCHAR2)
     RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
     vMsg varchar2(100):= '';
BEGIN
     IF pName   = 'Peter' THEN
          vMsg := 'Hello Peter. I am a student in Database Systems.';
     END IF;
     RETURN vMsg;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks I got it now :-D

Comment: Just note that initialising vMsg as '' is redundant, as an empty string is null in Oracle, which is what vMsg would be initialised to anyway.

Comment: yup, he could use `vMsg varchar2(100);` instead `''`